# Paypal sending an email to confirm and complete the payment

Tags: .net, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

1. From my website, www.wellnesstoday180.org, when I am going to buy a product, its taking me to the website and saying me to pay.
2. When I pay from my paypal account, it redirects to my website.
3. But actually my merchant account is not credited or my paypal account is not debited the price.
4. more over an email is sent saying that "Want to complete your PayPal payment at WELLNESS TODAY 180?" ....Below is the image from the email.
   [image]

It should not send any email to confirm the payment. what should I do in this scenario? In sandbox mode it was absolutely fine.

Comment: Have you tried to contact the Paypal support?

Comment: I have created a support ticket. but yet not replied. in the meantime, i thought, it could be a known issue, so I posted here.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue as well.  I believe that this may be due to a cache policy that is too aggressive on your site, and the UID that should be generated fresh is being resubmitted to PayPal and causing the failure.